# Tell me usage of out there

Tags: pronouns, nouns, relative-clauses

I send you out there.
Is this correct one? Otherwise Any other suggestions for usage of "out there".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may send somebody "out there"

Other examples include:

"Will you be going to the pool soon?"  "I'm going out there tomorrow"

"To all you sad people out there, I'm going to try to cheer you up!"

[**Here's a webpage with 300 sentences and phrases**](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/out_there.html) I suggest looking through if you want a good variety of examples

Comment: Which situation We able to use "out there"?

Comment: In nearly all situations where there is somewhere "out," you may say *out there* as a way to refer to it without saying its specific name (kind of like replying to someone using "it." Saying *out there* is not very formal, however.

Comment: your suggestion is useful and great! In the way Could you please share your email id?