# what does **out there** mean?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/NHTJPd7cnBU?t=63) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> "I spent quite some time in India before I joined the army.
>   I went **out there** climbing, and up in West Bengal and all around Darjeeling.
>   We were in Calcutta for a while and then we were with the Indian Army as well."

This [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/164147/108307) talks about the usage of *out there* without giving its meaning.

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thing?q=out%20there) does not have an item about *out there*.

[merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out-there) gives

> : UNCONVENTIONAL

which does not seem an explanation.

what does **out there** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "**went out** there" - the addition of *out* emphasises the fact that the destination is a long way off. See definition 2 [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-out).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful. I thought that sentence is a combination of "go doing" and "out there". Is that another way to break the sentence down?

Comment: "I **went out** there [to India] [in order to go] climbing."